# Its cool outside and fan runs loud and constant and temp guage reads 160

Tags: chevrolet, temperature, silverado, fan

I have 2015 Chevy Silverado and it's pretty cool outside around 50 s or so. My fan is running loud and constant. Temp gauge reads 160 lowest it will go fan a lot louder than normal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively common problem with these trucks.  It appears that the problem is with the Engine Coolant Temperature (ECT) sensor or its wiring.  When the ECU doesn't get a signal from the ECT, it doesn't know if the coolant is too hot or not and so as a failsafe, it runs the fan at 100% to avoid overheating.

The dash temperature gauge is controlled by the temperature data on the vehicle's CAN bus and since that signal is "0" the gauge reads the minimum which is 160F.

Some things to check:

1. It's possible that a bubble in the cooling system can lead to this.  Make sure your system is properly purged and has no leaks.
2. Check the ECT gauge connector and wiring for damage.  On this model I believe it's located above the water pump housing on the front of the engine.
3. Check the ECT itself and try replacing it.